# Linux: get all connect calls for a local port

Tags: networking, ssh, wireshark, tcpdump

I have a ssh tunnel through which a client is connecting to a server. Using, `wireshark`, I could see a periodic connection of SSH besides the keepalive, but I am unable to obtain the process (`pid`) that's causing this traffic.

I used `ss -ntap -o state all '( dport = :22 )'` in a while loop, but it captures only the `keepalive` connections from the local port that `ssh` listens on.

```
 tcp        0      0 192.168.132.126:52998   10.10.100.102:22 \
 ESTABLISHED 0          10619644   8875/ssh
```

How can I get the process-id that causes `ssh` traffic for this connection ? In other words, how can I get all connect calls initiated for `10.10.100.102:22` ?

Comment: Bump up the verbosity of that ssh tunnel, and have it log to a file?  You should see connections in the debug output.

Comment: Yes, verbosity does show more info in `/var/log/secure` for the direct `tcp/ip` connections.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty.

1. Use `iptables -A INPUT ... -j DROP` to temporarily drop packets going to the local port.
2. Then `sleep 10`
3. Gather `ss -antp`, chances are that your connections will be hanging there with (I think) status `SYN`
4. Then reload a iptables firewall to revert all your changes.
5. The TCP retransmition mechanism will cause your hung connections to continue. They will only get delayed.